# Remove arrow when segue is connected to prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to add labels to my prototype cell, however whenever I add a segue in the storyboard (control + dragging from cell to next view controller). The storyboard resets and it looks like the following image. Is there a way to remove the arrow on the right and have a blank cell in my table view that segues when tapped?

[image: prototype cell after segue added]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Storyboard, select the prototype cell and look at the attributes inspector on the right.  Change the cell accessory (which probably currently says "disclosure indicator") to "none".